# compare index and column in data frame with dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'A-A': 1, 'A-B':2, 'A-C':3, 'B-A':5, 'B-B':1, 'B-C':5, 'C-A':3, 
      'C-B':4, 'C-C': 9}
```

and a list:

```
L = [A,B,C]
```

I have a DataFrame:

```
df =pd.DataFrame(columns = L, index=L)
```

I would like to fill each row in df by values in dictionary based on dictionary keys.For example:

```
   A   B  C
A  1   2  3
B  5   1  5
C  3   4  9
```

I tried doing that by:

```
df.loc[L[0]]=[1,2,3]
df.loc[L[1]]=[5,1,5]
df.loc[L[2]] =[3,4,9]
```

Is there another way to do that especially when there is a huge data?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, though it's probably not the *best* way:

```
for index in L:
    prefix = index + "-"
    df.loc[index] = [d.get(prefix + column, 0) for column in L]
```

Calculating the `prefix` separately beforehand is probably slower for a small list and probably faster for a large list.

### Explanation

```
for index in L:
```

This iterates through all of the row names.

```
    prefix = index + "-"
```

All of the keys for each row start with `index + "-"`, e.g. `"A-"`, `"B-"`… etc..

```
    df.loc[index] =
```

Set the contents of the entire row.

```
                     [                           for column in L]
```

The same as your comma thing (`[1, 2, 3]`) just for an arbitrary number of items. This is called a "list comprehension".

```
                      d.get(                , 0)
```

This is the same as `d[        ]` but returns `0` if it can't find anything.

```
                            prefix + column
```

Sticks the column on the end, e.g. `"A-"` gives `"A-A"`, `"A-B"`…

Comment: Thank you @wizzwizz4. I tried your way but I got 'keyError', it seems that some combination of indices and columns don't  have correspond keys.Do you know how to insert zero to missing values?thanks

Comment: @H.E If this was helpful, also consider voting it up. (Same with the other answer, too!)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way that I can think of:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# given
d = {'A-A': 1, 'A-B':2, 'A-C':3, 'B-A':5, 'B-B':1, 'B-C':5, 'C-A':3, 
      'C-B':4, 'C-C': 9}
L = ['A', 'B', 'C']

# copy the key values into a numpy array
z = np.asarray(list(d.values()))

# reshape the array according to your DataFrame
z_new = np.reshape(z, (3, 3))

# copy it into your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(z_new, columns = L, index=L)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work if it wasn't sorted, like in Python 3.5.

Comment: Thank you @Shreyas, I will try it.

Comment: @H.E Note: this will fail _drastically_ if you've got missing slots. Otherwise, it's theoretically the best solution… but your data's reality doesn't seem to match this code's requirements.

Comment: I agree, but I feel like the data is sort of a graph structure and hence proposed my solution...